# Folder access in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to access a page `allCommonPageLink.jsp` from another page named `add_edit.jsp`

[image: Folder structure]

I have done `<%@ include file="/plan/common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" %>`

Error `/WEB-INF/ViewPages/plan/add_edit.jsp (line: 8, column: 42) File "/plan/common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" not found`

> NEW QUESTION:: 
>   how can I access an image form images folder from tray.jsp and add_edit.jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use

```
<%@ include file="../../common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" %>
```

Using ../ takes you back to the previous directory from where you are now.

If your page is web-inf/viewpages/plan/page.html that means that your working dir is plan. Invoking ../ takes you to view pages. Invoking another ../ takes you to web-inf. And from web-inf you have access to the file by accessing common/anotherpage.jsp

You can read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal for more info

Comment: Can you tell how to decide ../../

Comment: New problem arrived to access that I have done `../images/switcher-2col.gif`

Answer (score 4):

make it

```
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" %>
```

Comment: common is not under ViewPages but under WEB-INF

Answer (score 4):

the file `allCommonPageLink.jsp` is not under the `plan` folder, fix he path and try again, hope this would fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
<%@ include file="common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" %>
```

OR

You have to go back up to two folders **plan** and **viewPages** in order to access this folder in that file so this will work for you

```
 <%@ include file="../../common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

`<%@ include file="../../common/allCommonPageLink.jsp" %>`

When you add `../` it it will refer its parent folder or directory.